# How to hide conditionally the New button when ShowNewButtonInHeader is used?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

**Summary:** I need to show the New button only for users that have the role (here *manager*). I do not know how to do it when the new button is placed in the command column header.

**Details:** I am using DevExpress 14.2. When the New button in the `ASPxGridView` is used in the command column at the row, I can hide it in the CommandButtonInitialize event handler:

```
protected void gv_CommandButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCommandButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
    switch (e.ButtonType)
    {
        case ColumnCommandButtonType.New:
            e.Visible = Page.User.IsInRole("manager");
            break;
    ...
    }
```

However, when the property `ShowNewButtonInHeader` is set to true, it should probably be done differently. I have found some hints to use `Init` or `Load` items. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. If you know a better approach, I will accept your answer:

```
protected void gv_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
    foreach (GridViewColumn col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col is GridViewCommandColumn && !Page.User.IsInRole("manager"))
        {
            (col as GridViewCommandColumn).ShowNewButtonInHeader = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```